# How to make IE query the system and respond accordingly?

Tags: c#

My user go to my company's website and logs in to view information. I want my users not being able to login unless they have a particular antivirus installed.
So, If they have (for example) trend micro installed they should be able to login and if not they should not be able to.

Help is highly appreciated.
A.D

Comment: Are you concerned that a virus on the machine logging in to your *website* will infect the server?

Answer (score 2):

If that is for corporate / domain use, then group-policy might be a better option.

Trying to do this in a browser is going to be tricky; since it is IE you *could* perhaps do something *awful* with an activex control, but that is opening *one* security hole to check that a *different* security hole is closed. And the activex one is (IMO) of more immediate concern! Also consider that by default, or by choice, most options will be locked down.

And even if you get it working for IE; for virtually any *other* browser you don't have such options - and designing *just* for IE is... (chooses words carefully) against best practice.

But also; for a *web-site*, how is it *necessary* to know this? Especially if it is your web-site: simply, don't put malware on there, and don't leave XSS holes. My **bank** doesn't demand any specific anti-virus, after all.

Comment: In a corporate environment where the rules can be dictated to the users there are better options than system scanning. However as a normal web user I would not use your site if I had to allow it to perform a system scan first, for any reason at all.

Comment: @Dan - indeed; a memo with mention of disciplinary action may do more